# Fluent Nhibernate Compound Id slows perfomance

Tags: performance, fluent-nhibernate, compound-key

I'm refactoring legacy project with many views.
 Currently it works rather quick by simply selecting data from view. But after refactoring selecting slows perfomance. I looked through the sql send to db, it almost the same, except some aliases set to fields, but this view doesn't has any primary key, so in order to make it work in fluent nhibernate i added a complex key. View has about 10k of rows.
 So I think delays are on the client side according to some nhibernate key checks.
 Can smbd help resolve this?
 Thanks.

Comment: If anyone have workarounds, please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well actually the current docs of nhibernate talk about the draw backs of composite Id, as an a alternative solution you might add a simple key and do a query over the unique fields, this should be faster.

Comment: I'd wait a little, maybe there would be another answers. But I'd prefer not to change view, cuz there are to many of thems.